# mint 14 mate: window manager doesn't work after reinstall mate-panel & mate-applets

Tags: window-manager, mate-desktop

After doing a

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mate-panel mate-applets
```

and a

```
sudo apt-get install mate-panel mate-applets
```

for trying to get rid of a trayicon issue on my system, the mate window manager seems to be not working anymore.

after login, I still get a gui, but only a terminal is running in there. Also no panel and menus are available. for this terminal and any other application I'll start, except chromium-browser (brings its own decoration), no window borders shown at all.

when I start `mate-control-center`, following errors shown in term

```
** (mate-control-center:2116): WARNING **: error raised: [libslab_get_mateconf_value: error getting /desktop/mate/applications/main-menu/lock-down/user_modifiable_apps]

** (mate-control-center:2116): WARNING **: error raised: [load_xbel_store: couldn't load bookmark file [NULL]

** (mate-control-center:2116): WARNING **: get_actions_list() - PROBLEM - Can't load gtk-theme-selector.desktop

** (mate-control-center:2116): WARNING **: get_actions_list() - PROBLEM - Can't load mate-cups-manager.desktop
```

temporary, a manual start of `mate-panel` & `marco` via console is my workaround to have the system used as good as normal. but I'd like to get the default windowmanager works as expected.

I don't know which additional information I should provide at this point.